# PyAudio missing Import VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, import, pyaudio

I'm trying to use PyAudio in VSCode:

```
import os
import wave
import threading
import sys

import Pyaudio
```

but I keep getting an "import not found" error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\tangu\OneDrive\Bureau\Python 101\AudioLoop.py", line 7, in <module>
    import Pyaudio
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Pyaudio'
```

I've tried everything I could find online, but nothing has worked... When I type `pip show PyAudio`, it says it's installed within conda:

```
C:\Users\tangu>pip show PyAudio
Name: PyAudio
Version: 0.2.11
Summary: PortAudio Python Bindings
Home-page: http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/
Author: Hubert Pham
Author-email:
License: UNKNOWN
Location: c:\users\tangu\anaconda3\lib\site-packages
Requires:
Required-by:
```

But even running the code through Jupyter in VSCode in a kernel that specifically includes pyaudio, I still can't get it to recognise it...

I have no idea how to solve this.

Comment: Can you make sure you have the correct Python interpreter selected in VS Code? This can be different than what the terminal in VS code is referencing.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_select-and-activate-an-environment

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install python-pyaudio
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pyaudio
```

Comment: I'm on Windows... I can't use sudo apt-get

Comment: It could be that VSCode is using a different interpreter or different environment. Check in the lower left status bar what environment is used. To change, go to the settings and search for "Python interpreter".